# In Rails applying regex within a helper not being applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know the regex works. I tested it with Rubular and should work fine but it's not actually applying to my code.

I have the following present:

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center>
 <h3> <%= @region.name %> </h3>
<div class="row">
 <% @region.locations.each do |location| %>
  <div class="col-sm-6 location-small>
   <label>#{location.name} (#{location.abbreviation})</label>
   <p class="location-small"><%=other(location.hours_operation)%></p>
   <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

For my helper I have the following:

```
def other(string)
  string.split(/(?<=\) )/).join("\n")
end
```

It's showing on the page as:

```
7:30 AM - 5:00 PM (M-F) 7:30 AM - 12 PM (Sat)
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
7:30 AM - 5:00 PM (M-F) 
7:30 AM - 12 PM (Sat)
```

It looks like it should apply but it's actually not. I've tried changing the helper to be something like.

```
 def other(string)
   string.to_s.split(/(?<=\) )/).join("\n")
 end
```

I've even tried just putting the regex on location.hours_operation and nothing.

EDIT:
I've also tried the following:

```
def other(string)
  puts string.to_s.split(/(?<=\) )/).join("\n")
end
```

This strips out the line completely.

```
def other(string)
  string.to_s.split(/(?<=\) )/).join("\n")
  string
end
```

This does nothing. The same if I did return string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `string.split(/(?<=\) )/).join('<br>').html_safe`. HTML ignores `\n` linefeeds.

Also, `<label>#{location.name} (#{location.abbreviation})</label>` uses Ruby string interpolation, `#{}`, which ERB does not use. Try `<label><%= location.name %> (<%= location.abbreviation %>)</label>`

Comment: I'm actually using slim but for based on experience I also post in ERB. Actually used <p> instead as <br> required multiples to get the right line break.

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving Phlip's response as correct but since I hit some issues with html_safe I ended up using instead:

```
string.gsub(/(?<=\) )/, '<p>')
```